Connect vim-dadbod with postgres instance running in docker without having to install postgres locally
Some context. I am running postgres on my local machine using docker compose. Together with the compose is also pg-admin, but I want to avoid having to open pg-admin all the time and started looking at doing sql related stuff directly in nvim.
I came across vim-dadbod and vim-dadbod-ui. Installation was fairly simple. (I use Lazy as my package manager)
Setup as follows:
return {
  {
    "tpope/vim-dadbod",
  },
  {
    "kristijanhusak/vim-dadbod-completion",
  },
  {
    "kristijanhusak/vim-dadbod-ui",
    init = function()
      vim.g.db_ui_use_nerd_fonts = 1
      vim.g.db_ui_save_location = "../"
    end,
  },
}

I am able to run the :DBUI command and it opens the vim-dadbod-ui.
I was able to add the connection using the following connection url postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres. Doing this adds the postgres db to the list of available connections, but as soon as I want to access this I get an error (Screenshot below) saying `Error connecting to the db postgres: DB: 'psql' executable not found.
To be clear, I don't think this is an issue with vim-dadbod-ui since I also tried this with just vim-dadbod using the following command: :DB postgresql:// and had the same error of DB: 'psql' executable not found
I was able to reproduce on my macbook as well.
What I gather from the error message is that I need pqsl installed. I assume this is the postgres executable? I tried searching but as soon as I add 'postgres docker' to my search results, I get bombarded by everything that just doesn't help me solve my problem.
What am I missing? Do I really need postgres installed locally for this to work? Or can I somehow redirect it to the docker instance of postgres?


You probably need to use the container image's package manager to add a psql that will work in that container. Do you know what your container image is based upon? Do you have either apt or dnf available? Perhaps apk? Try using one of those to list available packages and perhaps find the one that includes psql.

Welcome to [vi.se]!

Use the plugin's issue tracker.

You need a postgres-client package available. The correct name depends on what the underlying linux distribution you are using. Try searching docker containers for postgres-client

Thanks @ChristianBrabandt and filbranden (can only notify one user). You got me on the right track. I needed psql. I ended up having to install psql locally, but not the entire postgres database. This is something I can live with. Since I do not have any rep here, I can't upvote your comments or mark them as helpful, but know that they truly were helpful.

@MarkArrow feel free to post an answer describing what worked for you, it's ok to self-answer and some of the details might be useful to future readers who are looking for solutions to a similar issue

Like the error suggests, 'psql' needs to be installed for the plugin to work.
The plugin makes use of the 'psql cli' to run the database queries.
The container I used already contained a 'psql' executable, but I was not able to get the dadbod-ui plugin to use the executable located within the container.
I ended up installing only the 'psql cli' locally without the rest of the postgres suite. When running the postgres installer, you are able to select "command line tools" and deselect the others.
